# Is it possible to save settings(variables) inside EXECUTABLE?

Tags: c#

I know saving/loading settings from Registry/local file... But is there any way to load some settings and variables from Standalone `.exe` itself?  (not to touch registry or any external file) and to save some settings inside the executable again...

For example, I used variables like this inside filename:

```
 projectfor_MikeFranklin@mail.com_1991.exe
```

so, in application, I used regex to catch first and second underscore `_` and then got values as variables... So, this was the only method for me, to send the STANDALONE file to other person with my defined variables..

Now I think, if there is a way to write/read such variables into file properties or elsewhere, which will pass when I send file to other persons..

Comment: Why not just use hardcoded values or external configuration files? Relying on file name pattern seems rather error prone

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen OP wants to override/mutate those variables

Comment: As far as i am concerned, the correct way for this would be using app.config / web.config. I don't know of any way to store mutatable variables inside IL Code

Comment: Per marked duplicate, you can't write to the running .exe. If you want to be able to send a single file, combine an appropriate data file with the .exe in a .zip archive. Then you can send the .zip archive as a single, standalone file. When unpacked into a directory, the data file will be present and usable by the .exe when running.

Comment: Firstly, you should get executable file name System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName. Then, you can do whatever on this string.

Comment: it may be possible using a combination of self extracting archives + auto run and repacking from the temporary folder and overwriting your original archive. A link that might be useful if it is possible at all http://superuser.com/questions/42788/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-file-after-extraction-from-a-7-zip-self-extracting-a But this is more of a hack than an intended use, if it works at all.

Comment: No Guys, offered solution (to repack and write in 3rd party file) is not wanted at this moment. however, thanks..